# Python, is it possible to take the pexpect sendline output and add a contion on it?

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

I have a problem that I can't find the answer.

I use the Python pexpect module to connect by ssh to a child application and I perform commands like "ls", "history" and ...etc. I need help, to do operations like retrieve the sendline output and check if it contains a specific String chaine or other operations of that kind. 
Can somebody please help me?

This is a simple example of the code I use:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh -l karaf -p 8101 localhost')
child.logfile = open("/home/user/python_HR/logs.txt", "w")
child.expect('password:')
child.sendline(mypassword)
child.sendline(command1)
```

Here I need to perform an "if" which will check if the result of child.sendline(command1) contains the string chaine "test"

I already know how to save all outputs in a log file. Also before and after attributes don't help me. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to `expect()` something, such as the prompt, and then use the `.before` property to see what has been printed before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are hitting the EOF then you can have code like this:

```
index = pexpect.expect(['test', pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT])
    if index == 0:                                          
        do_something()
    elif index == 1:
        print(pexpect.before)
    elif index == 1:
        print(pexpect.before)
```

I expect that if you expect the EOF that you will be able to use .before attribute.

Alternatively:
You can execute the command and pipe it's output to a file then download the file and work with it locally.

and if you want you can gain control manually by using pexpect.interact()

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I was so surprised. The solution you propose can surely help me. There is one thing I was trying, if I continu to use choice = child.expect('blabla'), then Icheck the choice value It can work also. The problem is if it does not find "blabla " it generates an pexpect.EOF exception. Is there any other solution to do not get this exception?